# Step functions task for existing lambda in CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I am new to CDK and we have existing lambda resource and I want to use the lambda function as task in CDK. RunLambdaTask is expecting the lambda function. Is there a way to get the lambda function from the arn?

```
       submit_job = sfn.Task(
            self, "Submit Job",

            task=sfn_tasks.RunLambdaTask("how to get the lambda function")
            result_path="$.guid",
        )
```

Comment: any update? let me know if it's working

Comment: Thanks. It worked as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the lambda function using ARN you need to use - `lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn`.

**Usage:**

```js
const lambdaARN = `arn:aws:lambda:${region}:${accountID}:function:${lambdaName}`
const importedLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(scope,'importedLambda',lambdaARN)
```

**Full example:**

```js
      createRunLambdaTask(scope: cdk.Construct,lambdaARN: string,resultPath: string,duration: number = 1200,name: string): sfn.Task {
      const importedLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(scope,`${name}-lambda`,lambdaARN)
      const task = new Task(scope, name, {
        resultPath: resultPath,
        timeout: Duration.seconds(duration),
        task: new tasks.RunLambdaTask(importedLambda, {
          integrationPattern: sfn.ServiceIntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
          payload: {
            "token.$": sfn.Context.taskToken,
            "Input.$": "$"
          },
        })
      });
      return task;
    }
```

More about [fromFunctionArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html#static-from-wbr-function-wbr-arnscope-id-functionarn).

**Update-**

I have just noticed you work with Python and not Typescript. basically, this is the same implementation. Follow [from_function_arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html#aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function.from_function_arn) documentation about how to import existing lambda.

And later pass the `IFucntion` object to `RunLambdaTask`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working.  The cdk synth keeps complaining with 
"Task Token is missing in payload (pass Context.taskToken somewhere in payload)"

The IDE also complains on the face that the payload is not compatible with the TaskInput.

Comment: I guess there might be some changes with CDK since The guys from CDK release a new version every few weeks. open a new question and I'll be happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since lamdba function names are unique. There's also the [fromFunctionName](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Function.html#static-fromwbrfunctionwbrnamescope-id-functionname) method that only needs the name.

```js
const importedLambda = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(scope,'importedLambda',lambdaName)
```