# AWS CDK application how to "reference" already created aws lambda function (without creating a new one in a stack)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I've created a lambda function called `add` in my aws environment, I am trying to build a cdk application that would generate a new API Gateway and then invoke `add`.

I am following the tutorial on https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/30-hello-cdk/300-apigw.html and I noticed all the examples I came across online seem to write their code in a similar form to following:

```
   const hello = new lambda.Function(this, 'HelloHandler', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,    // execution environment
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),  // code loaded from "lambda" directory
      handler: 'hello.handler'                // file is "hello", function is "handler"
    });
    const api = new apiGateWay.LambdaRestApi(this, 'api', {
      handler: hello
    })
```

Above example directly creates a new lambda function name with `HelloHanlder` in it. I want to reference my previously created function `add`, and not add any new lambda function to the stack, something along the lines of:

```
    const api = new apiGateWay.LambdaRestApi(this, 'api', {
      handler: "add"
    })
```

Is this possible to fix?

Comment: how did you create the lambda function `add`? did you do it manually or you used cloudformation or another cdk stack?

Comment: I manually created it first, so then I tried creating another cdk app with only lambda in it -- I can reference lambda source code by doing this. But doing this ends up creating a new function and not referencing `add`. Sorry I am entirely new to this so I might've mixed up terms.

Comment: you can import an existing aws resource into cdk, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825766/step-functions-task-for-existing-lambda-in-cdk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option 1: Using existing Lambda from function Arn

```
const hello = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(
  this,
  "hello-lambda",
  "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111222233333:function:hello-lambda"
);
new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, "Endpoint", {
  handler: hello,
});
```

Option 2: You can import existing lambda into a new CloudFormation stack and export the Arn and import into CDK

- [Example of import a DynamoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65557316/aws-cdk-working-with-existing-dynamodb-and-streams), Lambda is no different
- [Exporting Arn as stack output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html)
- Importing stack into CDK and using it.